# does Silverlight support webcam or microphone?

Tags: silverlight, webcam, microphone

`Flash` has `webcam` and `microphone` support for **live** video and audio transmission, and using them is really easy in Flash. It takes only a few lines of ActionScript code to invoke the camera object.
`Camera.get` - Returns a default or specified camera object, or null if the camera is not available.
`Camera.setMode` - Sets aspects of the camera capture mode, including height, width and frames per second.
`Camera.setMotionLevel` - Specifies how much motion is required to invoke 
`Camera.onActivity(true)` and how much time should elapse without motion before `Camera.onActivity(false)` is invoked.

I want to know that is Silverlight support webcam or microphone? If yes then as easily as Flash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and yes.

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/webcams/

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-4-videos/access-web-camera-microphone/

Silverlight is very straight-forward in support for mics and cams.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Silverlight supports Webcam and Microphone. There were a log of good demos that showed use of both hardware intelligently. You can check [this talk](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/12/16/silverlight-4-demos-from-my-pdc-keynote-now-available.aspx) from ScottGu's PDC keynode that is a project that shows how to get a picture from your webcam and get the data from Amazon based on the scanned barcode. The tutorial is available [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/news/Using-the-WebCam-as-a-Barcode-Scanner.aspx).